# mongoose index not work, when use mocha

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

## My project files:

I have a `User` model:

**user.model.js**

```
var UserSchema = new Schema({
    username:        { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
    location:        { 'type': {type: String, enum: "Point", default: "Point"}, coordinates: { type: [Number], default: [0,0]} },
});

UserSchema.index({location: '2dsphere'});
```

And have an Express route:

**user.route.js**

```
function create(req, res) {
    User.create(req.body, function(err, user) {
        if (err) return res.send(err);

        return res.send(user);
    })
}
```

**user.test.js**

```
describe('test_user', function() {
    it('create user', function(done) {
        request('http://localhost/user')
            .post('/')
            .send({
                username: 'john',
                password: "123"
            })
            .end(function(err, res) {
                if (err) cb(err);
                done()
            });    
    });
});
```

I have  a `drop_databse.js` file, it run every time before run test:

**drop_databse.js**

```
var MongoClient = require('mongoose/node_modules/mongodb').MongoClient


MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost/miccity_test', function(err, db) {
    if (err) return console.log(err);
    db.dropDatabase(function(err) {
        if (err) return console.log('drop databse failed!! :\n' + err);
        db.close();
    })
})
```

## when I test

when I run test:

```
$ node drop_database.js && mocha

  test_user
    ✓ create user


  1 passing (21ms)
```

But, I notice `user` collection in database has not index of `location` field !

But I create a single file:

**test.js**

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema       = mongoose.Schema;

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/miccity_test');
var db = mongoose.connection;
db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'mongodb connection error:'));


var UserSchema = new Schema({
    username:        { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
   location:        { 'type': {type: String, enum: "Point", default: "Point"}, coordinates: { type: [Number], default: [0,0]} },
});


UserSchema.index({location: '2dsphere'});

var User = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);

User.create({username: "test"}, function (err) {
    if (err) console.log(err);
})
```

And run: `node drop_databse.js && node test.js`, then i check the index of location, it exist!

Is it mean mocha can not create index of collection?

**Edit:**

## i found the trick way:

use `Model.ensureIndexes` to Sends ensureIndex commands to mongo for each index declared in the schema.

```
function create(req, res) {
    User.ensureIndexes(function(err){
        User.create(req.body, function(err, user) {
            if (err) return res.send(err);

            return res.send(user);
        })
}
```

it is maybe a bug for mongoose, I already submit this issue to github.

Comment: try running your test again with the `location` field set in your `User.create` call

Comment: @JoshC. But if I have too many `create`, that's very bad